# Ajax Search Field with labels for node types

Tags: search

I'd like to have a search field with ajax and some kind of label for the node type. Similar to http://www.finanzen100.de . Is there any module or other ways of getting this for drupal 7 (or 6)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can [Inline Ajax Search](http://drupal.org/project/inline_ajax_search) cover your needs?